# How can I resize an image within Canvas with Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

While trying to create an app including an image within a canvas by Tkinter, I got some problems with resizing the image. The first one is that "from PIL import Image, ImageTk" does not work in PyCharm IDE, and shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'". The second one is not understandable for me since I am a novice in coding. It happened when I run the python file that I mentioned in cmd.
Could you help me to understand the problem and what I can do with it?

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
image = Image.open("BG.png")
    image = image.resize((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #self.pw.pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    
myCanvas = Canvas(root, bg = "white", height=600, width = 600)
myCanvas.place(x=550,y=100)#pack()
myCanvas.create_image(0,0, image=image,anchor="nw")
myCanvas.place(x=550, y=100)

app=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Error shown in cmd:**

```
  File "tk.py", line 50, in <module>
    myCanvas.create_image(0,0, image=image,anchor="nw")
  File "C:\Users\hahik_zvw4rds\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2785, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\hahik_zvw4rds\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2771, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=500x500 at 0x1A1BB564550>" doesn't exist
```

Comment: pip install Pillow in terminal or just go to file -> settings -> python interpreter -> click on the '+' sign at the bottom then search for pillow -> install package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commented out code is correct. You need to convert the Image to a PhotoImage for tkinter to be able to use it.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
image = Image.open("BG.png")
image = image.resize((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    
myCanvas = Canvas(root, bg = "white", height=600, width = 600)
myCanvas.place(x=550,y=100)#pack()
myCanvas.create_image(0,0, image=pic, anchor="nw")
myCanvas.place(x=550, y=100)
myCanvas.image=pic

app=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```